# How to create azure virtual machine via api?? (not the classic one, the one which on new azure manage portal)

Tags: python, azure, azureportal

I would like to create azure new virtual machines via api or python sdk, the one which we have on azure's new manage portal, which allow me to use features like operate the machine's `network security group` on the portal. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKxmf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Visual Studio Resource Group Project, which will help you Generate the JSON Template for the VM and you can submit the template using Powershell or APIs Directly,

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('vhdStorageName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "[variables('vmSize')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
      "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
      "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
        "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
        "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
        "version": "latest"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "osdisk",
        "vhd": {
          "uri": "[concat('http://', variables('vhdStorageName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('vhdStorageContainerName'), '/', variables('OSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
        },
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
      }
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "diagnosticsProfile": {
      "bootDiagnostics": {
        "enabled": true,
        "storageUri": "[concat('http://', variables('diagnosticsStorageName'), '.blob.core.windows.net')]"
      }
    }
  },
```

for the Power Shell Script

```
# Create or update the resource group using the specified template file and template parameters file
```

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) 
                                   `-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName`
                                   -TemplateFile $TemplateFile 
                                   `-TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile`
                                   @OptionalParameters `
                                   -Force -Verbose

Comment: thank you very much! Very useful

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use Azure Resource Management Template that enables you to use a declarative form of the environment you wish to create
Description of the template is here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/
You'll find many samples on GitHub (look for azure-quickstart-templates)

If you still wish to use python SDK you'll have to make the corresponding REST API calls. A nice article about this way is here :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2015/02/12/azure-resource-manager-creating-an-iaas-vm-within-a-vnet.aspx

Hope this helps
Best regards
Stéphane

Comment: thx, it has been very useful.

Comment: I'm wondering if they will update their python SDK to make it do the job